# r rgl quads3d with only 3 unique vertices does not show color

Tags: r, colors, rgl

R 3.5.1
rgl 0.99.16
Windows 10 version 1809 build 17763.195

Under some circumstances (I think if it's the two internal points), if two of the four points provided to a `quads3d()` are the same, then the resulting shape does not display its assigned color, instead it's black. In the following example, note that the second and third points are the same:

```
q1 <- matrix(c(-0.35, 0, -0.5,
                0.35, -0.5, 0,
                0.35, -0.5, 0,
               -0.35, 0, 0.5),
             byrow=TRUE,
             ncol=3,
             dimnames=list(c("C0", "Cl", "Dl", "D0"), c("x", "y", "z")))

quads3d(x=q1[,"x"], y=q1[,"y"], z=q1[,"z"], color="blue", alpha=1)
```

This code produces a triangle (as it should, see screen shot), but it's always black.[Object should be blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3oDb.png). Changing just the coordinates produces a blue shape.

I can work around this, but I would call it a bug. I think quads3d should work properly with only three of the four points passed to it being unique - that does not violate the documentation (its all in one plane and convex). I'm reporting it here in case anyone has helpful information about it, and for future searchers.

Thanks.

Comment: Current OpenGL recommends that you don't use quads:  see https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Quads.

Comment: If you specify the normals, it's fine, so likely what's happening is that the calculation of the normal vector is based on a cross product where one vector is length zero.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it represents a lack of understanding of OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I know that rgl is based on OpenGL, but this is an R question, quads3d is an rgl thing. Is it not recommended to use quads3d in R now? What is the recommended alternative?

Comment: Use triangles instead of quads.